# how to set ImageView using glide and DataBinding : MVVM

Tags: android, mvvm, android-glide

How can we use data binding in android to put the image in an ImageView by using Glide? I have seen some example but not anyone helped me. I need to set url in glide but I'm stuck in many tutorials definition or examples.

I tried to set image using xml and data binding but it not working

Another Problem: The image view image set on button click I want it set on when the app is started.

```
public class LoginViewModel extends BaseObservable {
    private User user;


    private String successMessage = "Login was successful";
    private String errorMessage = "Email or Password not valid";

    private String URL_1 = "https://sftextures.com/texture/2704/0/2703/wallpaper-pattern-primitives-shades-of-grey-smaller-details-abstract-huge-texture-256x256.jpg";
    private String URL_2 = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/eb/Breathe-preferences-desktop-wallpaper.svg/128px-Breathe-preferences-desktop-wallpaper.svg.png";

    @Bindable
    private String toastMessage = null;

    @Bindable
    private String url = null;

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.url);
    }

    public String getToastMessage() {
        return toastMessage;
    }


    private void setToastMessage(String toastMessage) {

        this.toastMessage = toastMessage;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.toastMessage);
    }


    public void setUserEmail(String email) {
        user.setEmail(email);
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.userEmail);
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getUserEmail() {
        return user.getEmail();
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getUserPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    public void setUserPassword(String password) {
        user.setPassword(password);
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.userPassword);
    }

    public LoginViewModel() {
        user = new User("","");
    }

    public void onLoginClicked() {
        if (isInputDataValid()) {
            setUrl(URL_1);
            setToastMessage(successMessage);
        }
        else {
            setUrl(URL_2);
            setToastMessage(errorMessage);
        }
    }

    public boolean isInputDataValid() {
        return !TextUtils.isEmpty(getUserEmail()) && Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(getUserEmail()).matches() && getUserPassword().length() > 5;
    }
}
```

xml

```
<ImageView
                android:layout_width="123dp"
                android:layout_height="123dp"
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                bind:imgUrl="@{viewModel.url}"/>
```

MainActivity

```
 @BindingAdapter({"bind:imgUrl"})
    public static void setProfilePicture(ImageView imageView, String imgUrl) {
        Glide.with(imageView.getContext()).load(imgUrl).into(imageView);
    }
```

Comment: The `BindingAdapter` looks fine to me. Do you have the internet `user-permission` in the `AndroidManifest`?

Comment: are you using `xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` in import xml?

Comment: @Blackbelt just added internet user-permission and it solves my problem 
Thank you so much